# Proper method and code in R to complete PCA to determine if I can reduce variables prior to doing k-means cluster

Tags: r, pca

I apologize in advance for the question here as it is rather vague.   What I have been searching for is the proper way to complete PCA on a data set with 300k records and 30+ variables.   My ultimate goal is to do cluster analysis.  I have done this with relatively good outcome.   I would like to complete PCA to determine if I can reduced the number of variables.   I've been searching the internet for some time now and not finding 100% of the answer - some great information but not getting me there.   What I would like to do is use PCA to determine the most important variables to use to support streamlining my cluster analysis.  I would also like to determine if there is any multicollinearity in the variables I could avoid.   I completed PCA but struggling to tie this back to the actual variables in the data.  Any help or suggestions on a resource by link would be awesome!!  Thank you!!

Comment: I think the general issue you're having is that PCA isn't generally used for the purpose of variable selection. What kind of modeling techniques are you looking to use after you select your variables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done quite simply:

1. **Perform PCA**, decide on the number of components you want to keep. Save weights.
2. For each observation, **calculate component scores** (linear combination of weighted sum of variable values - Note, that it is best to first re-scale all variables, preferably before step 1).
3. **Perform cluster analysis on the component scores**.

END.

---

You have done step 1, so now you just need to do step 2 and 3.

To answer the other question: multicollinearity is rarely an issue for PCA unless you have correlations like 0.98, 0.99.